# Exporting a complicated dictionary into a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which the values are list. here is an example:

example:

```
d = {'20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33456_12.RCC': [1.0354477611940298, '0.51'],
     '20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33457_05.RCC': [1.0412757973733584, '1.09'],
     '20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33505_06.RCC': [1.0531309297912714, '0.81']}
```

I am trying to export this dictionary into a `csv` file. like this expected output:

expected output:

```
file_name,citeria1,criteria2
20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33456_12.RCC,1.0354477611940298, 0.51
20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33457_05.RCC,1.0412757973733584,1.09
20190606_CFMPB576run3_CF33505_06.RCC,1.0531309297912714,0.81
```

to do so, I made the following code:

```
import csv

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    header = ["file_name","citeria1","criteria2"]
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(d)
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Edit your question and add what it returns. This way we don't have to try it ourselves.

Comment: It doesn't return anything; `my_dict` isn't defined.

Comment: `for k,v in d.items(): w.writerow([k] + v)`. You'll just need a `csv.writer` instead of a `DictWriter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change as follows:

```
import csv

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    header = ["file_name", "citeria1", "criteria2"]
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(header)
    for key, lst in d.items():
        w.writerow([key] + lst)
```

A `DictWriter` is given the field/column names and assumes the rows to be provided as dictionaries with keys corresponding to the given field names. In your case, the data structure is different. You can use a simple `csv.writer` as your rows are a mixture of keys and values of your given dictionary.